# Native HTML 5 drag and drop that actually drags?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for an example of the new HTML5 native "draggable" behavior that actually drags the source (i.e. the source fallows the mouse up to the destination).

So far I wasn't able to find one, maybe you know of any!

Comment: -1 Flagged for migration to StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you mean the source follows the mouse up to the destination? Like the file? How should that be visualized?

Comment: @Xeon06: When you drag something you can get a small rectangle right to the mouse OR you get the object you are dragging (image, file, whatever) as a transparent object. I want the transparent object to fallow the mouse to the destination... all done with the new capabilities of HTML5. So far I only found examples with the small rectangle and once dropped, the source disappears in a blink and appears at the destination.

Comment: @JohnDoDo you mean like the file icon? Does [this example](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload) show what you want to do?

Comment: @Xeon06: something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/ but HTML5 + plain javascript, not with plugins or libraries.

Comment: @JohnDoDo okay so you're not looking for file drag and drop? Have a look at this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you're after [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)